# Can I use wired and wireless headphones in the same time?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a bluetooth headphones which work with my windows 8 machine. I want both: wired and wireless headphones to work in the same time. But if wireless headphones device is connected to a machine, then wired headphones doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

I found a solution [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/142036-can-t-use-bluetooth-headphone-my-wired-earpiece.html). The procedure suggested here is:

1. Open Sound panel
2. Select Speakers as the default playback device
3. Go to the "Recording" tab
4. Right click and enable "Show Disabled Devices"
5. A recording device called "Wave Out Mix", "Mono Mix" or "Stereo Mix" (this was my case) should appear
6. Right click on the new device and click "Enable"
7. Right click on the new device and click "Set as Default Device"
8. Double click on the new device to open the Properties window
9. Go to the "Listen" tab
10. Click on the "Listen to this device" checkbox
11. Select your bluetooth headphone device from the "Playback through this device" list and you're done.

but step 5 doesn't work: I don't get any new devices.

Comment: watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e24c8i6xloU

Comment: @MuhammadA: thanks, I installed Realtek manager, but still don't get Sounx Mix device. I'm on a dell laptop.

Comment: Sorry buddy that solution works for some people, but like yourself it doesn't work for me. In fact its impossible, since all the solutions try and make two different sounds play at once, one for like skype and one for music. Windows cannot play the same sound through multiple devices with any method as far as I have read.

Comment: @MuhammadA: that's not my case: I want to play the same stuff, but direct sound to two different devices at the same time: to my wired and wireless headphones. The point is to make use of my wireless headphones and be able to watch a movie together with somebody else using the wired headphones.

Comment: Yes I have the same issue, I ended up ordering a hard splitter on the audio jack. Which I will use to plug two sets of headphones in,  too bad I wont be able to use the BT headphones but that's how it is.

Comment: @MuhammadA: I have it, and it is working. But then I have to keep 2 pairs of wired headphones + 1 pair of wireless headphones. Or I shouldn't use wireless headphones at all.

Comment: For any who come across this question but are using Windows 10, see the solution here: https://www.intowindows.com/use-speakers-headphones-at-the-same-time-in-windows-10/